# Wildfly Custom form authentication configuration

Tags: java, wildfly-10

How to add custom authenticator in Wildfly? In JBoss 4.2 it was like below:

In \jboss-as\server\production\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\META-INF\jboss-service.xml, add the following in :

```
 <java:property>
      <java:key>MY-CUSTOM-AUTH</java:key>
      <java:value>com.test.MyCustomAuthenticator</java:value>
 </java:property>
```

How to add the custom authenticator in wildfly 10

Thanks in Advance!